# Как правильно написать "data:" в ajax запросе, чтобы в PHP файл передавались все данные формы?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, веб-программирование

```
function getdetails2(){
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "action_ajax_form2.php",
    data: ???????
}).done(function( response ) {
    $("div.testing").html(response);
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getdetails2(){
  $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "action_ajax_form2.php",
      data: new FormData("тут ваша форма"),
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
  }).done(function( response ) {
      $("div.testing").html(response);
  });
}
```

Comment: а просто `data: { field: "value"} ` нельзя?

Comment: @teran так ТCу надо "**все** данные формы"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский судя по предыдущим вопросам, у ТСа там одно-два поля

Comment: @teran ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   я не шпионю за ним 